# Should private and protected variables, methods, and classes be commented?

Tags: coding-style, comments

When creating a private or protected variable, method, class, etc., should it be commented with the documentation comment?

Comment: Off-topic.  But, yes, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! The comments are to help any developer - yourself included - when reviewing, maintaining or extending the code in future. Whether it's public/private shouldn't be an influencing factor, quite simply if you think something isn't clear enough without a comment, put one in.

(Of course the best documentation is clear self-documenting code in the first place)

Answer (score 1):

Some people will no doubt tell you that nothing **needs** to be commented (and technically they are right in that comments have no effect on output). However, it's up to 'coding style' like you tagged it as. I personally always comment all variables in addition to giving them a descriptive name. Remember other people may want to work with your source, or you might want to in a years time, in which case it's worth the few seconds to document it while you still know what it does.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely yes. When for example you find a bug in your code after like three months, with commenting it will be easier to recall what this code was supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

Commenting individual variables is occasionally helpful, but more often than not variables will have logical groupings that will be expected to uphold certain invariants.  A comment describing how the group as a whole is supposed to behave will often be more useful than comments describing individual variables.

For example, if an `EditablePolygon` class in Java might contain four essential fields:

```
int[] xCoords;
int[] yCoords;
int numCoords;
int sharedPortion;
```

and expect to uphold the invariants that both arrays will always be the same length, and that length will be >= numCoords, and all coordinates of interest will be in array slots below `numCoords`.  It may further specify that there may exist multiple `EditablePolygon` objects sharing the same arrays, provided that all but one such object has a `sharedPortion` greater than `numCoords` or equal to the array length, and that one object's `sharePortion` is no less than the `numCoords` value of any of the others [making a clone of a shape require a defensive copy unless a change is requested to part of the original which was shared with the clone, or to any part of the clone [which is entirely shared with the original].

Note that the most important things for the comments to document are (1) the array lengths may exceed the number of points, and (2) certain portions of the array may be shared.  The first may be somewhat obvious from the code, but the second will likely be far less obvious.  The field `sharedPortion` does have some meaning in isolation, but its meaning and purpose can really only be understood in relation to the other variables.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good practice to document methods and Classes. Moreover javadocs for public methods should be more stressed as those act as reference manual for external objects. Similarly Javadoc could be beneficial for public variables, though i personally is not in favor of having comments for variables.